# Using completion handlers for sequential querying Firestore collections

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am querying a list of restaurants via the main function just below here. Then I use the list of restaurants to get a list of meal plans they have from another collection:

```
MealplanCalls.getRestaurants(userId: userId) { (restaurantList, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self.showError(show: "Error", display: error)
            } else {
                var currentPlansArray = [Mealplan]()
                var restaurantIndex = 0
                while (restaurantIndex < restaurantList.count) {
                    MealplanCalls.getPlans(restaurantId: restaurantList[restaurantIndex]) { (mealplans, error) in
                        guard let mealplans = mealplans, mealplans.count > 0 else { return }
                        self.planArray.append(contentsOf: mealplans)
                        print("empty : \(self.planArray.count), \(self.planArray)")
                        if let error = error {
                            self.showError(show: "Error", display: error)
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.planTable.reloadData()
                        }
                    currentPlansArray.removeAll()
                    restaurantIndex += 1
}
            }
        }
```

Here is the service where I get the list of restaurants:

```
static func getRestaurants(userId : String, completionHandler : @escaping ([String], String?) -> Swift.Void) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("Restaurant_Data")
        var restaurantList = [String]()
        db.whereField("users", arrayContains: userId).getDocuments { (restaurantSnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completionHandler([], error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                for document in restaurantSnapshot!.documents {
                    restaurantList.append(document.documentID)
                }
                completionHandler(restaurantList, nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is where I get mealplans:

```
static func getPlans(restaurantId : String, completion : @escaping ([Mealplan]?, String?) -> Void) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("Meal_Plans")
        db.whereField("restaurantId", isEqualTo: restaurantId).order(by: "hour", descending: false).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion([], error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                let mealplans = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap { (queryDocuments) -> Mealplan in Mealplan(dictionary: queryDocuments.data(), mealplanId: queryDocuments.documentID, opened: false, menuItems: [MenuItems(menuItemName: "", menuItemQuantity: "")])!}
                completion(mealplans, nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is in my tableview I just see one of the meal plans repeated planArray.count times. I think the main question is where do I reload the tableview?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dispatchGroup to solve this problem

```
MealplanCalls.getRestaurants(userId: userId) { (restaurantList, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self.showError(show: "Error", display: error)
            } else {
                var currentPlansArray = [Mealplan]()
                var restaurantIndex = 0
                let group = DispatchGroup()
                
                while (restaurantIndex < restaurantList.count) {
                    group.enter()
                    MealplanCalls.getPlans(restaurantId: restaurantList[restaurantIndex]) { (mealplans, error) in
                        guard let mealplans = mealplans, mealplans.count > 0 else { return }
                        self.planArray.append(contentsOf: mealplans)
                        print("empty : \(self.planArray.count), \(self.planArray)")
                        if let error = error {
                            self.showError(show: "Error", display: error)
                        }

                    group.leave()
                    currentPlansArray.removeAll()
                    restaurantIndex += 1
               }
            }
                
                
                group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {

                  self.planTable.reloadData()
                })
              
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried dispatch group in a variety of different ways and I still end up with an empty array or with the array objects repeated.

Comment: Would it make more sense to use sempahore here?

Comment: If your issue is technical in nature not code specific you can seek assistance at the free Firebase Support here [1].  

[1] https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?authuser=0